# How to change the tag of an image in the resources file

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, tags, resources

I'm trying to change the tag of all the images in the resources file so i can set them a value (i'm using playing cards).

So i get the image like that :

```
Properties.Resources._10Diamonds //The ten of diamonds card
```

so now i'm trying to actually change the tag value by doing that :

```
Properties.Resources._10Diamonds.Tag = 10; //Trying to change the tag value to 10
```

but this doesn't do anything just like if the Tag property wasn't existing.

So is there a way to change the tag value of an image in the Resources file ?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) also please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Flagging for deletion. Please pay attention to @Plutonix and his advice. Good luck!

Comment: You can change the `.Tag` of a `Bitmap` object after you assign it a graphics resource.

Comment: Resources is not a collection of objects.  It is a *factory* of objects, so your image doesnt really exist until you assign it to something.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] like you agreed to when you joined.

Comment: This is a perfectly fine question imo (at least as it is now) and the fact that his 2nd line doesn't bring up a compiler error is the next one, not yet answered. Imo a bug.

Comment: Well it doesn't bring up an error but it just passes through and do nothing.

Comment: Yes. `Properties.Resources._10Diamonds` is not a Bitmap, it searches for it and hopefully returns it. So the compiler ought to catch the the line that adds a Tag but it doesn't; we have to live with it: The resources can't be changed like this. I think you could use Reflection for it, though I doubt a Tag even exist in there; but probably it is not a good idea anyway..

Comment: I finally used a whole different way to get my image and it now works thanks guys for your time !